# pySmartDL "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, download, pysmartdl

Recently I started getting errors when I try to download something using [pySmartDL](https://github.com/iTaybb/pySmartDL). This app is hosted on [Heroku](https://heroku.com).

```
2022-02-14T08:56:00.996352+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread Thread-31:
2022-02-14T08:56:00.996359+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-14T08:56:00.996363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
2022-02-14T08:56:00.996591+00:00 app[web.1]: self.run()
2022-02-14T08:56:00.996602+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
2022-02-14T08:56:00.996893+00:00 app[web.1]: self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2022-02-14T08:56:00.996935+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pySmartDL/pySmartDL.py", line 654, in post_threadpool_actions
2022-02-14T08:56:00.997073+00:00 app[web.1]: total_filesize = sum([os.path.getsize(x) for x in args[0]])
2022-02-14T08:56:00.997082+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pySmartDL/pySmartDL.py", line 654, in <listcomp>
2022-02-14T08:56:00.997223+00:00 app[web.1]: total_filesize = sum([os.path.getsize(x) for x in args[0]])
2022-02-14T08:56:00.997232+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
2022-02-14T08:56:00.997317+00:00 app[web.1]: return os.stat(filename).st_size
2022-02-14T08:56:00.997366+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/downloads/1445283714/AllDownloads/16448289470289521/Hello.mkv.000'
```

What is possible reason for this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution: You can solve the issue by downloading "Hello.mkv.000" (or any other file) directly in your root directory.

Also just for reminder, Heroku deletes all your external files once you restart your app.

Comment: Actually main file name is `Hello.mkv`. pySmartDL downloads by splitting file into some parts. But as we can see first part download fail. And some other files are downloading on same folder without any issue. Just problem with this file. Also I can download same file manually from any browser without any issue. Only getting problem with pySmartDL.